# How to update group in df after iteration

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to apply an operation to each data frame group, and then update the corresponding rows in the original data frame. However, the new values are not being inserted at the correct locations. Effectively, I am trying to `diff` within each group.

```py
mydf = pd.read_csv("my.csv")
mydf["forwardDelta"] = np.NaN

for name, group in mydf.groupby(["a", "b"]):
    group["forwardDelta"] = group["c"] - group["c"].shift(1)
    for index, row in group.iterrows():
        mydf.iloc[index, 4] = row["forwardDelta"]
```

Comment: Can you explain more `mydf.iloc[index, 4] = row["forwardDelta"]` ?

Comment: The fifth column is `"forwardDelta"` of the original data frame. So I used `4` since I am using `iloc` with the `index`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think here no loops are necessary - use [`DataFrameGroupBy.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.diff.html) and if need set values in 5th column use [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) with `:` for select all rows:

```
mydf = pd.DataFrame({'a':[5,8]*3,
                      'b':[1,2]*3,
                      'c':[2,7,5,4,3,9],
                      'd':list('abcdef'),
                      'e':range(5,11)}).sort_values(['a','b'], ignore_index=True)


print (mydf)
   a  b  c  d   e
0  5  1  2  a   5
1  5  1  5  c   7
2  5  1  3  e   9
3  8  2  7  b   6
4  8  2  4  d   8
5  8  2  9  f  10

mydf["forwardDelta"] = mydf.groupby(["a", "b"])["c"].diff()

mydf.iloc[:, 4] = mydf["forwardDelta"]

print (mydf)
   a  b  c  d    e  forwardDelta
0  5  1  2  a  NaN           NaN
1  5  1  5  c  3.0           3.0
2  5  1  3  e -2.0          -2.0
3  8  2  7  b  NaN           NaN
4  8  2  4  d -3.0          -3.0
5  8  2  9  f  5.0           5.0
```